# Render Contents of Menu Tab upon entry in ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application that has a left hand nav.  When the user navigates to my app they are dropped onto the menu tab.  When this happens the mycontent object should render but it doesn't until the user navigates away from Menu and back to it.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening.  Here is my code:

Server.R

```
server = function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    shinyjs::runjs('Shiny.setInputValue("selected_tab", "current_tab");')
  })
  useAutoColor()
  js_code <- "
    // Change the title color and size using JavaScript
    var portfolioTextElement = document.querySelector('sidebar');
    if (portfolioTextElement) {
      portfolioTextElement = '#FFF' !important; // Change to your desired color
    }
  "
  shinyjs::runjs(js_code)
  
  observeEvent(input$sidebarItemExpanded, {
    shinyjs::runjs('$(".menu-item-text").removeClass("active");')
    shinyjs::runjs('$(".menu-item-text").click(function() { $(this).addClass("active"); });')
  })
  
  
  #app button --------------------------------------------------------------
  output$btnVal <- renderText(input$myAppButton)
  observeEvent(input$myAppButton, {
    showModal(modalDialog("Thanks for clicking me!", easyClose = TRUE))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$dark_mode, {
    toast(
      title = if (input$dark_mode) "Dark theme on!" else "Light theme on",
      options = list(position = "topRight", class = "bg-warning", autohide = TRUE)
    )
  })
  
  output$basic_cards_tab <- renderUI({
    tagList(tabItem(
      tabName = "portfolio",
      fluidRow({
        num_rows <- nrow(applicationData)
        print(num_rows)
        if (num_rows == 0) {
          print("This Worked")
          fluidPage(
            title = h2("Not Found"),
            closable = FALSE,
            width = 8,
            status = "danger",
            solidHeader = FALSE,
            collapsible = FALSE,
            tags$h5("We're sorry. We were not able to find any application access to you. Please contact Admin for inquiry"),
            tags$hr(),
            tags$h6("Contact Details:"),
            tags$h6("xx@xx.com"),
            tags$h6("xxx@xx.com"),
            tags$hr(),
            tags$iframe(
              src="https://xx.com/contact", 
              style = "border: none;
                       overflow: hidden;
                       height: 500;
                       width : 70%;",
              sandbox = "allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
            )
          )
        } else {
          print(applicationData$name[1])
          lapply(1:nrow(applicationData), function(i) {
            print(applicationData$name[1])
            box(
              title = applicationData$name[i],
              closable = FALSE,
              width = 4,
              status = "warning",
              solidHeader = FALSE,
              collapsible = FALSE,
              label = boxLabel(
                text = HTML(paste('<p style="font-family: Arial;">', applicationData$abbrev[i],'</p>')),
                status = "primary"
              ),
              userPost(
                id = 1,
                image = ifelse(is.null(applicationData$image_url[i]),
                               g_default_image,
                               applicationData$image_url[i]),
                author = NULL,
                description = applicationData$description[i]
              ),
              actionButton(paste0("app_link_", i), "Open", class = "btn-primary btn-sm")
            )
          })
        }
      })
    )
    )
  })
  
  output$mysidebar <- renderUI({
    #applicationData <- appData()
    print(nrow(applicationData))
    if(nrow(applicationData) != 0) {
      lapply(1:nrow(applicationData), function(i) {
        menuItem(
          text = HTML(paste('<p style="color:white;">', applicationData$name[i], '</p>')),
          tabName = paste0("app_tab_", i),
          selected=TRUE,
          icon = icon("laptop-code", style = "color: #FFFFFF") 
        )
      })
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  })
  

  output$mycontent<-renderUI({
    
    #applicationData <- appData()
    items <- c(
      list(
        # tabItem(
        #   tabName = "report"),
        tabItem(
          tabName = "portfolio",
          uiOutput("basic_cards_tab"))
      ),
      lapply(1:nrow(applicationData), function(i) {
        url_link<-applicationData$url[i]
        tabItem(tabName = paste0("app_tab_", i), 
                tags$iframe(
                  src=url_link, # local deployment
                  style = "border: none;
                   overflow: hidden;
                  height: 1000px;
                   width : 100%;
                   # position: relative;
                   # top:15px;
                   # padding:0;",
                  sandbox = "allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
                )
        )
      })
    )
    # render
    do.call(tabItems, items)
  })
  
  

  observe({
    #applicationData <- appData()
    if(nrow(applicationData) != 0){
      lapply(1:nrow(applicationData), function(i) {
        observeEvent(input[[paste0("app_link_", i)]], {
          value<-paste0("app_tab_", i)
          print(input$current_tab)
          newtab <- switch(input$current_tab, "portfolio" = value,value= "portfolio")
          updateTabItems(session, "current_tab", newtab)
        })
      })
    }
  })
  
  output$userData <- renderReactable({
    applicationData <- appData()
    userdata <- UserData()
    reactable(userData
    )
  })
  
  output$admin_tab <- renderUI({
    
    list(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "adminTab",
        reactableOutput('userData')
    )
    )
  })
  
  output$homePage <- renderUI({
    tagList(tabItem(
      tabName = "portfolio",
    box(
      title = "App",
      closable = FALSE,
      width = 8,
      status = "warning",
      solidHeader = FALSE,
      collapsible = FALSE,
      label = boxLabel(
        text = "Visualize your data",
        status = "primary"
      ),
      userPost(
        id = 1,
        image = "https://www.xx.com/img/home-process.png",
        author = NULL,
        description = "Visualize your data"
      )
    )
    )
    )
  })
  
  # update sidebar ----------------------------------------------------------
  
  observeEvent(input$sidebarToggle, {
    updateSidebar(id = "sidebar")
  })
}
```

UI.r

```
thematic_shiny()

ui = dashboardPage(
  # Creates a loading screen with secondary blue.
  preloader = list(html = tagList(spin_1(), "Loading ..."), color = "#2078A8"), 
  help = NULL,
  dark = NULL,
  fullscreen = TRUE,
  scrollToTop = TRUE,
  header = dashboardHeader(
    # Below tag changes color of the nav bar.  !important prioritizes this tag over any other things that 
    # may impact it
    #155070
    tags$style(
      HTML(
        "
        .sidebar {
          background-color: #155070 !important; 
          font-color: #fff !important;
          font-family: Source Sans Pro !important;
        }
        
        .current_tab {
          font-color: #fff !important;
          background-color: #155070 !important; 
          font-family: Source Sans Pro !important;
        }
        
        .sidebar .treeview-menu > li > a {
      color: #fff !important; /* Change the font color for menuItem text */
        }
        .nav-link.active {
          background-color: #9caeb8 !important;
        }

        .menu-item-text.active {
    color: #9caeb8 !important;
  }
        "
      )
    ),
    title = dashboardBrand(
      title = HTML('<p style = "color:black;font-family: Source Sans Pro">Brand Menu</p>'),
      color = "white",
      href = "https://XX.com/",
      image = "IMG.JPG",
      opacity = 0.8
    ),
    fixed = TRUE,
    logout_ui("logout",classbutton = "btn-primary btn-xs",textbutton = HTML('<p style = "color:black;margin: 5px;">Log Out</p>'))
  ),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    fixed = TRUE,
    skin = "light",
    status = "info",
    id = "sidebar",
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "current_tab",
      flat = FALSE,
      compact = FALSE,
      childIndent = TRUE,
      sidebarHeader(title = HTML('<p style="color:white;"></p>')),
      menuItem(
        text=HTML('<p style="color:white;font-family: Source Sans Pro">Menu</p>'),
        #badgeColor="info",
        #badgeLabel = "home",
        tabName = "portfolio",
        #id="tab_portfolio",
        icon = icon("bars", style = "color: #FFFFFF")
        
      ),
      
      uiOutput("mysidebar")
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    uiOutput("mycontent"),
    tags$head(
      tags$script(
        HTML("function openWebsite() {
             window.location.href = 'https://www.example.com/';
           }")
      ),
    )
    
  ),
  controlbar = NULL,
  title = "App Menu"
)
```

Comment: Without having executed your code so far, I guess the problem is `renderUI` related - you might be able to solve it via `outputOptions(output, "yourUiOuput", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)`. Is there any specific reason for its extensive use? You should avoid it - from [Mastering Shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#dynamic-basics): `This is one of the downsides of renderUI(); relying on it too much can create a laggy UI.` You'll also find alternatives following the link I shared.

Comment: What's an alternative?

Comment: E.g. using `tabsetPanel(type = "hidden")` or `conditionalPanel()`.

Comment: It's not that it's laggy though, it's literally not showing anything until I click a different tab and then click back to menu

Comment: Yes - the first part of my comment is specific to your problem, the second part is a general advice. Tbh I'd have more motivation looking into it if your example would be minimal - but it is lengthy.

Comment: ah gotcha, I see.

Comment: PS: if you really want to create your dashboardSidebar on the server-side, check `?shinydashboard::renderMenu()` instead of `renderUI`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73035977/9841389) is why. Personally, when it comes to dynamic UI components I'd try to solve as much as possible in the UI part of the app (client side) to avoid the detour to the server.

Comment: Thansk, that makes sense as general advice, however I'ms till stumped as to why it isn't rendering and how I could go about fixing it.

Comment: Please try to provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-workflow.html#getting-help).